# Bitlocker, the manufacturer partitions and NTFS

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, ntfs, bitlocker, windows-backup

I have just bought this Probook 450 G2 with Freedos. Initially there was two manufacturer partitions, each about 8 GB, one for HP documents and the second for something else. I deleted the one about documents and but didn't delete the other thinking it is critical. Apart from these two small partitions, I split the drive into 4 other partitions. I installed Windows 10 on the first, and I shifted to 8.1 and the same problem. I think the problem lies in the manufacturer FAT32 partition.

The problem is when I want to turn on Bitlocker for the Windows drive, it asks for NTFS even though the C partition, but not that of the manufacturer, is so already.

I cannot delete the FAT32 drive. When I try through Disk Management, the system says: "Windows cannot delete the active system partition on this disk."

I get the same error when I try to use third-party apps like EaseUS.

I don't want to delete that partition, but it causes me much trouble. Apart from the problem of Bitlocker, because of this partition, I cannot use System Image Backup. When I try to do so, the system chooses the C drive as well as the problematic partition because it is a System drive, and I cannot deselect it. I cannot create the system image backup either as I receive an error saying that it is not formatted NTFS.

I wonder why would HP create a partition in FAT32 that cannot be deleted and that prevents me from using critical apps like Bitlocker and System Image Backup.

Please help me!

Here are some screenshots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

Content of the problematic/manufacturer partition through EaseUs app

[image]

Comment: @Ramhound Thank you for the comment, but I think the comment shows you didn't read the post because the questions you asked are covered in the post with its 7 pictures.

Comment: @DavidPostill As I said in the post, "I cannot delete the FAT32 drive. When I try through Disk Management, the system says: 'Windows cannot delete the active system partition on this disk.'" It cannot be deleted by third-party software, like EaseUs, too. Thank you!

Comment: If you searched for "windows delete active system partition" you would have found [Windows 7: Cannot delete an active system partition?](http://www.sevenforums.com/performance-maintenance/117597-cannot-delete-active-system-partition.html/)

Comment: @Ramhound That "something else" partition is the content of which are shown in the last picture by EaseUs app. I didn't specify what it is because I wasn't sure and because I gave many pictures and because I thought I'm not required to know everything and it is because of my ignorance that I'm posting this question.

Comment: @DavidPostill thank you for the helpful comment. Another question please. The content of the partition I'm about to delete are shown in the last picture. Is it safe to delete the manufacturer partition, I mean aren't these things critical for the laptop?

Comment: See the first comment by Ramhound.

Comment: @DavidPostill Please is it safe to delete the partition without backing up my data because the problematic partition itself prevents me from backing up the data as shown in the post? Also, I hope someone will write a comprehensive answer, that deserves to be chosen as answer, and that will be helpful for other people as well.

Comment: @MofaHa - The only way to solve your problem is to delete the partition.  I went ahead and deleted my comments, I am done, I have to walk away from a question once I feel I am getting "non-answers" or I get the indication you are frustrated by my attempts to help.